# How to download a file in a lightning datatable using the download icon

Tags: files, datatable

I'm hoping someone can provide me guidance on this since I haven't been able to find an answer.

I have created a lightning datatable which displays delete and download icons on each row. I am able to delete the file using the code below. However, I can't figure out how to download the file without hardcoding a recordId.

Could someone please provide assistance on how I can download a file based on the row? I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing. I truly appreciate it.

```
{
 async handleRowAction(event){
        const actionName = event.detail.action.name;
        switch ( actionName ) {
            case 'delete':
                const result = await LightningConfirm.open({
                    message: 'Are you sure you want to delete file?',
                    variant: 'headerless',
                    label: 'Confirmation',
                });
                if(result){
                deleteRecord(event.detail.row.Id).then(() => {
                    refreshApex(this.fileData);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: "Record deleted successfully!",
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                        
                    ); 
                    return refreshApex(this.refreshTable);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("error, " + error);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error deleting record',
                            message: error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            })}
            break;

            case 'download':
                const rowId = 'event.detail.row.Id';
                const fileDownloadUrl = 
        `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/06976000001KfZ1AAK`;
                
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate] ({
                    type: 'standard__webPage',
                    attributes: {
                        url: fileDownloadUrl
                    }
                }, false);

            break;
            default:

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello , Does this discussion answer your question [How to generate a download URL for a ContentDocument in Lightning Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260937/how-to-generate-a-download-url-for-a-contentdocument-in-lightning-community) ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Subrat. It seems that article is for Communities, and I'm trying to do this for standard users viewing records. I'm just not skilled enough at this point to figure out the syntax for the method.